# Como fazer um filtro baseado em uma condição?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Tenho um data.frame com duas colunas (`CLASSWK` e `IND`) e gostaria de aplicar um filtro baseado em uma condição, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

Tenho uma coluna `CLASSWK`, que quero manter apenas os valores que forem iguais a 1 ou 2. Mas isso só se aplica se a minha outra coluna, `IND`, for diferente de 0.

Então, basicamente, se `IND == 0`, eu apenas desconsidero meu filtro, mas se meu `IND` for qualquer outro valor, então eu tenho que aplicar o filtro na coluna `CLASSWK` e retirar os valores que são diferentes de 1 ou 2.

Meu `dput`:

```
structure(list(CLASSWK = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 6, 7, 3), IND = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 8, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Código que tentei usar:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  filter(case_when(IND != 0 & CLASSWK == 1 & CLASSWK == 2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eis uma maneira com o pacote `dplyr`.
Como `CLASSWK` pode tomar vários valores usa-se `%in%` e não a igualdade.

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% filter((CLASSWK %in% 1:2 & IND != 0) | IND == 0)
#  CLASSWK IND
#1       1   1
#2       2   2
#3       1   3
#4       5   0
#5       1   6
#6       2   0
#7       6   0
```

---

Em R base, qualquer das seguintes maneiras também resolve o problema.

```
subset(x, (CLASSWK %in% 1:2 & IND != 0) | IND == 0)
x[(x$CLASSWK %in% 1:2 & x$IND != 0) | x$IND == 0, ]
```

Comment: mas em ambos os casos eu estou retirando da base os valores onde `IND == 0` e eu gostaria de mantê-los também.

Comment: @AlexandreSanches Feito, veja agora.

Comment: Muito obrigado!